# Patch multiple records to Dataverse depending on the number on form

Tags: powerapp, dataverse

I have a form in which I have 3 fields.

A text value: request

A number: number

And a choice that maps to a Dataverse choice: methods

When the user saves, I want to produce number times selected method records.

so for example, if users save:

**request**: ABC

**number**: 2

**methods**: M1, M2, M3

I want to save these rows in dataverse:

```
ABC,1,M1

ABC,1,M2

ABC,1,M3

ABC,2,M1

ABC,2,M2

ABC,2,M3
```

How do I populate records to Dataverse based on the number user enters?

I'm new to power apps and wondering what's the best way to do it? So far I successfully bind the choice to the Combo box and I can save one record at a time. Do I use a collection to save multiple records? Or would you rather use a Flow and a loop?

I'll really appreciate it if someone can tell me the best practice in this case.

Thanks

Ova

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to make a collection or use a flow. You can basically do a loop in Power Apps and create the records in that loop.

Based on your input here is a loop that for each method chosen by the end user will create a record in dataverse after they click the save button.

On screen visible create a collection that you use for the numbers dropdown (use the col_loops.dropdownvalue in the items of the dropdown):

```
ClearCollect(col_loops, {dropdownvalue: 1, loopvalue: [1]}, {dropdownvalue: 2, loopvalue: [1,2]}, {dropdownvalue: 3, loopvalue: [1,2,3]} )
```

On the save button insert this formula, it will loop over the numbers selected and for each number also loop over the methods selected.

```
ClearCollect(
    current_loop,
    {curloop: 0}
);
ForAll(
    LookUp(
        col_loops,
        Value(Dropdown1.SelectedText.dropdownvalue) = dropdownvalue
    ).loopvalue,
    Patch(
        First(current_loop),
        {
            curloop: LookUp(
                current_loop,
                curloop <> "dummy"
            ).curloop + 1
        }
    );
    ForAll(
        ComboBox1.SelectedItems.Value,
        Patch(
            testtable01S,
            Defaults(testtable01S),
            {
                textcol: TextInput1.Text,
                numbercol: 3,
                choicescol: ThisRecord.Value
            }
        )
    )
)
```

In the power app there are just 3 fields, a simple text input for the request, a dropdown for the number and a combobox for the methods. The items in the combobox binds to the choice field in dataverse (like you have done).

I tested on my end, and in the above scenario i get 6 records created in dataverse.